# How to optimize my code to return empty when meta value is NULL empty?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom WordPress theme and i generated a code to return data from meta values as following:

```
<?php if($values = get_post_custom_values("tagline")) { ?><h2 style="font-size: 12px;"><?php _e('Tagline:', 'psythemes'); ?> <span itemprop="headline"><?php echo $values[0]; ?></span></h2><?php } ?>
```

and it works fine, but when the meta value in empty in the database (NULL)
it prints "Tagline:"

so, i need to optimize the code to NOT print anything in the output HTML when the value is empty

Thanks

Comment: i think you need check database first, if NULL you dont need doing echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should check $values[0] before display something. If the value is empty(NULL) you don't need to display anything.

```
<?php 
        if($values = get_post_custom_values("tagline")) { 

            // printout if $values[0] is not empty
            if (!empty($values[0])) {
    ?>
                <h2 style="font-size: 12px;"><?php _e('Tagline:', 'psythemes'); ?> <span itemprop="headline"> <?php echo $values[0]; ?> </span></h2>
    <?php 
            }
        } 

    ?>
```